# Usage of working on

Tags: word-usage

my native language is Spanish. I want to say "Estaré trabajando en mejorar mis habilidades".
I find it natural to say "I will be working on improving my skills" but I don't find many examples of this, I mean a verb after working on. 
Could you tell me which is the right way to say it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a perfectly correct phrase. In this phrase, "improving" is not a verb but rather a [gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund), which roughly speaking is the "-ing" form of a verb that behaves like a noun. That's why it's perfectly grammatical to use after "working on".